# Android LivePerson Agent?

Tags: android, liveperson

Is there a liveperson agent for android? Specificly one which pushes notifications to your phone when people request a chat.

Comment: Please give some feedback. Did any of the answers help?

Comment: It is important to provide feedback to people who answer your questions. Rate the answers, and select the answer that best answers your question (click on the tick) - this also earns you points on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. LivePerson have a sample Android app

http://apps.liveperson.com/applistings/chat-from-android.asp

Comment: You could tweak the app to display alerts as David is suggesting, if it doesn't already do it.

Answer (score 0):

Android [Notification Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) and some listener to notify events